# django: gave up on user uploading its avatar. Image is not stored. Need help!

Tags: django, image, file-upload

I tried hard, but I couldn't make it. I am trying to find a way on how a user can upload its avatar image, using django and this is my code:

settings.py

`USER_IMAGE_PATH = '/site_media/user_data/images/'`

models.py

`fs = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.USER_IMAGE_PATH)`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(storage=fs, upload_to=settings.USER_IMAGE_PATH)
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    avatar = forms.ImageField(label='avatar', required=False)
```

urls.py

`(r'^profile/(\w+)/$', profile_form),`

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile_form(request, username):
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404(u'User not Found')
    if form.is_valid():
        avatar = form.cleaned_data['avatar']
        profile = user.get_profile()
        profile.avatar = avatar
        if not avatar:
            pass
        else:
            image_file = request.FILES['avatar']
            im = imageilb()
            filename, content = im.handle_uploaded_image(image_file)
            profile.avatar.save(filename, content)
```

imagelib.handle_uploaded_image()

```
import hashlib
from PIL import Image
import os.path
import StringIO
import django

def handle_uploaded_image(self,i):
    # resize image
    imagefile  = StringIO.StringIO(i.read())
    imageImage = Image.open(imagefile)

    (width, height) = imageImage.size
    (width, height) = self.scale_dimensions(width, height, longest_side=240)

    resizedImage = imageImage.resize((width, height))

    imagefile = StringIO.StringIO()
    resizedImage.save(imagefile,'JPEG')
    filename = hashlib.md5(imagefile.getvalue()).hexdigest()+'.jpg'

    # #save to disk - hardcoding of paths will be removed as soon as this thing works
    imagefile = open(os.path.join('/site_media/user_data/images',filename), 'w')
    resizedImage.save(imagefile,'JPEG')
    imagefile = open(os.path.join('/site_media/user_data/images',filename), 'r')
    return filename, django.core.files.File(imagefile)
```

With this code, the field in the database is inserted as the path of the saved image, correctly (although just the name of the image-file would be enough) but the image is not saved where it is supposed to be saved or not saved at all (I can't be sure if the file is stored somewhere else that is why I am saying this -- though I checked)
any more code will be added if requested.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look or even reuse django thumbnailing libraries such as [sorl.thumbnail](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/). Their code might give you a clue.

Comment: Thanks, I did have a look and it seems very neat. I didn't know it exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope my suggestion be helpful for you

settings.py

```
USER_IMAGE_PATH = '/site_media/user_data/images/'
```

models.py

```
fs = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.USER_IMAGE_PATH)
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(storage=fs, upload_to='avatar')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       if self.avatar:
           imglib.resize_image(avatar)
```

imglib.py

```
from PIL import Image

def resize_image(avatar, size=(200,200)):
    image = Image.open(avatar.path)
    image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS).save(avatar.path, 'JPEG', quality=75)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile_form(request, username):
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404(u'User not Found')
    if form.is_valid():
        avatar = form.cleaned_data['avatar']
        profile = user.get_profile()
        profile.avatar = avatar
        profile.save()
```

Comment: it is working, but image is saved twice. I think first time in  `image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS).save(avatar.path, 'JPEG', quality=75)` and the second time in `profile.save()`. I know because in `imglib.py` I added this line: `filename = hashlib.md5(username).hexdigest()+'.jpg'` to change the filename of the image and make it unique

Comment: also the path of avatar field in my database is pointing to the original file (not the resized one with the modified name)

Comment: on my opinion, you store link to resized file

Comment: yes, I think I know my error. Will try again and report back, soon (not at my pc right now). However during my tests I noticed that image save does not work when I am trying to upload a .gif. Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to doublecheck the opening slash in your paths (I assume you don't actually want  to save images in the root of your file system.)

i.e.

```
'/site_media/...'
```